# ServiceStack and OAuth2

Tags: servicestack

How can I use the existing servicestack oauth2 providers, google for example, and only limit it to one account that I create for my users?

Basically, I want to keep the Api access under check, so that not everyone who has a google account can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CustomValidationFilter` to add your own Custom Validation, returning a **non** `null` response will cancel Authentication and return the desired error response, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new GoogleOAuth2Provider(appSettings) { 
            CustomValidationFilter = authCtx => {
                if (!AllowUser(authCtx.Session, authCtx.AuthTokens)) {
                    var url = authCtx.AuthProvider.GetReferrerUrl(
                        authCtx.Service, authCtx.Session
                    ).AddParam("f","GoogleOAuthNotAllowed");
                    return authCtx.Service.Redirect(url);
                }
                return null; //Allow Authentication through
            }
        }, 
    }));
```

Comment: Is the AllowUser the method where I will be checking against my own database to allow for certain users?

Comment: ... what I mean is, how do I allow or deny the user access once Google authenticates it successfully

Comment: @user3500462 Yes `AllowUser` is your own custom method where you can inspect and verify the Users session and Google OAuth tokens and decide whether to deny them by redirecting back to the referrer page with a custom `?f= GoogleOAuthNotAllowed` which you can detect and provide a customized error page.